# PHP openssl not verifying signature string despite it looks like the original one

Tags: php, openssl

It's probably an encoding issue.

```
$sign2 = (stripslashes($_POST['sign']));
$sign2 = mb_convert_encoding($sign2, "auto");
```

code above is a result of trial-and-error method which made $sign2 look like $sign which is an output from:

```
openssl_sign($content, $sign, $key_pr);
```

but openssl_verify() returns false when I type $sign2 instead of $sign for verification - despite they are both of type string, length 128 and look the same.

> $sign: KOóÂ^0Å ¶Ô®þó :æ aêÌCæÃñÃ·”äþÊÝÌ7=ËæK-ÎËÚ¦iÛtËš½Då^Ðv¶:Å*^'¬˜8êšq
>
> $sign2: KOóÂ^0Å ¶Ô®þó :æ aêÌCæÃñÃ·”äþÊÝÌ7=ËæK-ÎËÚ¦iÛtËš½Då^Ðv¶:Å*^'¬˜8êšq
>
> verification: bad

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you [`base64_encode`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) the signature and then [`base64_decode`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) the string to verify the signature? (as is standard)

Comment: Jon, you are a genius :D (or perhaps I was an encoding ignorant)

Comment: Overdriven, for future reference, if you want to reply to someone you should use `@` and then start typing their name so they get notified of your response. ^^  Glad I was able to help though! =]